# Different Thread.Principal in web Api custom attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, action-filter, principalcontext

In a Web API, I've created a `TokenAuthentication` attribute to verifying token that has come from client and after that the user should sign in, then i use my `UserServiceManager` to sign in like this:

```
   ApplicationUser aUser = new ApplicationUser();
                user.CopyToModel(aUser);

                _signInManager.SignIn(aUser, true, true);
                //_signInManager.UserManager.CreateIdentity(authenticationType,"")
                //var l = _authenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfo();
                ////l.Login.
                //var authType = _authenticationManager.GetAuthenticationTypes();
                //var  cliamIdentity = _authenticationManager.CreateTwoFactorRememberBrowserIdentity(aUser.Id);

                var claims = new List<Claim>();
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email));
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserName));

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "CustomApiKeyAuth");

                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { identity });
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

                _authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true }, identity);

                return UpdateResult<SignInStatus>.Success(SignInStatus.Success);
```

I Used both `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User` to set Principal due to different thread in web api.

My purpose is the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` can be use in my api controller. then i set this in my `TokenAuthentication` Attribute after sign in:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
```

it doesn't work and  `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`  is still empty in api controller.I moved the above line in my action and worked but I don't want to write it in each of my actions. what should i do?

Comment: If you are in action, you can get from property called `User`, ex: `this.User` from `ApiController`

Comment: Thanks but I have a several services which are using Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name and i need to use this. I should assign this.User to Thread.CurrentPrincipal in my action too. as I told, I don't want such a assignment in each of my action. i need something happen in overall.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I decided to create a attribute inherited from AuthorizeAttribute to solve the problem and not to repeat the assignment in each action. but After reading the [AuthorizeAttribute source](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) i found another solution :

```
 actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
```

It was written in the custom `tokenAuthentication` attribute instead of `Thread.CurrentPrincipal = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User` and it worked. Now Thread.CurrentPrincipal  in the api controller has the correct principal.